# Javascript: disappearing object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

My problem is that I am trying to fill an object with arrays of data but some of the arrays either aren't getting set properly or disappear.

I've tried searching for an answer but I haven't found anything and I've also tried debugging but haven't been able to get to the bottom of the problem.

The function this happens in is a custom jQuery extension I've been working on which takes an object as input containing an array of 'hours':

```
Hour = {
  time: datetime,
  comment: string
};
```

The code is as follows:

```
(function ( $ ) {  
    $.fn.calendar = function(data){

    var times={};
    var debugging = {};
    var x = 0;

    data.hours.forEach(function(hour){
        //Transform hours.time into 1-7 day of the week
        //and 0-23 hour of the day
        //Save comments and timestamp to times[day][hour];
        var entry = new Date(hour.time);            
        var clockedTime = entry.toTimeString().match( /^([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})/ )[0];
        times[entry.getDay()] = {};
        times[entry.getDay()][entry.getHours()] = [clockedTime, hour.comment];
        debugging[x] = [entry.getDay(), entry.getHours()];
        x++;
    });
    console.log(times);
    console.log(debugging);

    return this.html(times);
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Console output:

```
Object {1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object}
Object {0: Array[2], 1: Array[2], 2: Array[2], 3: Array[2], 4: Array[2], 5: Array[2]}
```

So from the output, I know it's looping through the data six times (as the debugging object contains six items) but the times object only has four entries.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you have duplicates for `entry.getDay()` that are overwriting existing properties.

Comment: That would be it. I have two items for the same day but only the first appears. Is it not possible to have for instance distinct times[2][1] and times[2][2] entries?

Comment: Correct, not possible, otherwise how would you reference one or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your properties when you have duplicate `entry.getDay()` values. Try this instead:

```
times[entry.getDay()] = times[entry.getDay()] || {};
times[entry.getDay()][entry.getHours()] = [clockedTime, hour.comment];
```

That will create an object if the property doesn't exist, or leave it alone if it does.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I'd overlooked. Seems silly now but I just hadn't seen it.